# How to set background inactive and grey while i put a password to a QInputDialog in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, background, qinputdialog

How to set background inactive and grey while i put a password to a QInputDialog in QT?
I have an qmainwindow app and i would like to do this. Thanks your help! :)

```
bool ok;
    QString sPassword =  QInputDialog::getText(this, "Enter Password", "Password: ", QLineEdit::Password, "",&ok);
    if(ok && QString::compare(sPassword,"goodpassword",Qt::CaseInsensitive)==0)
        QApplication::quit();
```

Comment: Is your input dialog modal? If not, open it as modal one to block the background window.

Comment: I open as in my code, sorry for lame question but how can i open it as modal and block the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background should be inactive.
The `QInputDialog::getText` is modal by default, see the doc: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText

To grey out your application when the dialog is opened I'd say either play with the stylesheet or create your custom dialog that paints a grey rectangle on top of the application.